# .NET Multilanguage web project not working in production - Resx issue

Tags: .net, resx, production, multilingual

I am working on a web site application developed with VS 2008.

I am in the process of localizing a web application. I can generate the resx files and I can read the values from those files without any problem. When I ran the website in the localhost it works great in any language. The issue occurs when I deploy our website in the production servers.

It seems that the values from the resx files are not read.

I read lots of blogs and questions about this and I tried several solutions. I tried most of the possible configurations for the resx file.

The first configuration I tried is this:

- **Build Action:** Embedded Resource.
- **Copy To Output Directory:** None.
- **Custom Tool:** PublicResXFileCodeGenerator.
- **Custom Tool Namespace:** [empty].

As I mentioned before, this works great in localhost but not in the production server.

Then I changed the **Copy To Output Directory** property to **"Copy Always"** but the result is the same.

So, I decided to change the **Build Action** to **"Content"** but we get a **System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException** when we try to access the resource file from code behind. The way we access the Resx Property is the Following:

**wImage.AlternateText = App_LocalResources.SelectRecordSet_aspx.wImageActive;**

This happens in localhost and in production.

As I read in this post: http://www.mojoportal.com/Forums/Thread.aspx?pageid=5&t=6062~-1 I changed the Custom Tool Namespace To Resources and I renamed the way I accessed the property:

**wImage.AlternateText = Resources.SelectRecordSet_aspx.wImageActive;**

But that didn't work.

I've been struggling with this issue for a couple of days and I still can not find the proper solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: First: Is it a web page or a web application project?
Just for the sake of it: Did you try meta:resourcekey="..." would tell us if the resx are there and readable.

Comment: The project was created as an ASP.NET Web Application. We have the meta:resourcekey="..." for instance:                                                                **<dxwgv:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Lote Id" FieldName="RecordSetId" VisibleIndex="4"
                                Width="10px" meta:resourcekey="GridViewDataTextColumnResource1">**  The Main issue is that the multilanguage site works perfect when we ran it in Visual Studio but not in production. The build action we are using for the resx files is **Embedded Resource**.